# How to stop chrome from searching when manually typing in local dev addresses

Tags: html, google-chrome, cookies, jekyll, browser-cache

During development today I needed to clear my browsing data to test some cached information. I only selected cached images and files and cookies and plugin options. After this my development environment stopped being recognized the same way in chrome (Version 40.0.2214.91) and started being searched in google instead.

When I type `http://0.0.0.0:8080` or even `0.0.0.0:8080/` into the address bar the site is being accessed fine. When I click on links within the local site that point to pages such as `http://0.0.0.0:8080/category/index.html` I am taken to the correct page. It is only when I try to type in a url such as `http://0.0.0.0:8080/category/index.html` manually that Chrome decides it should search the web instead of going to the correct page as before. **There are no extra spaces on either side of the url.**

When testing this in Firefox everything works normally. Nothing has changed in my development environment unless you include the cache and cookie clear in Chrome.

Other similar questions seem to only address the issue from the perspective of the local server(MAMP,XAMP,WAMP) configuration, but I am not using these to serve my site. I am working in a jekyll installation that serves the site for me, and the config.yml values are correct as evidenced by the site behaving normally in Firefox.

Comment: I'm running into the same thing today. Typing "http://0.0.0.0:8080/" into the address bar results into a google search. Maybe a bug in a new version of chrome?

Comment: Link without quotation mark: [http://0.0.0.0:8080](http://0.0.0.0:8080)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently chrome no longer likes the use of 0.0.0.0. Use 127.0.0.1 instead.

See discussion on the subject here https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3048

Answer (score 2):

Create a bookmark which leads to http://0.0.0.0:4000 and Chrome will stop going to Internet to search for it.

It just worked on my Chrome 41.0.2272 (Mac). [Hexo JS](http://hexo.io) static web page server uses this address and I'd rather not change it to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: This works for a single URL, but even when you're at http://0.0.0.0:4000 and manually type in http://0.0.0.0:4000/pagename it will do a Google search instead of navigating directly. [Yosemite, Chrome 43.0.2357.134]